# how to stop countdown when time 00:00:00:00?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (NSString *)formattedCountdownTime {
    //Get the time left until the specified date
    NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.countdownStartTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600) % 24;
    NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);

    //Update the lable with the remaining time
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02li days %02li hrs %02li min %02li sec", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
}
```

Comment: why do you use so many blank lines?

Comment: Interesting question @vikingosegundo :D

Comment: keep a reference to the timer and if `ti` <= 0 invalidate it and display 00:00:00

Comment: Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ChrisH said, just reference the timer and add a condition in **updateTime** with this code:

```
if (ti <= 0) [self.timer invalidate];
```

*i can't upvote ChrisH's answer because i doesn't have 50 reputation*

**EDIT**

first reference your timer

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

in **startCountdown** change

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

with

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

in **updateTime** add this code just after your calculs

```
if (ti <= 0) [self.timer invalidate];
```

Voilà :)

Comment: Rather than defining ti within updateTime, set up ti either as a property (and use self.ti) or as a static variable for the whole class.